# Permission denied when GitLab Runner tries to fetch project

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up a pipeline with GitLab CI but I'm experiencing some problems on my Runner which is a shell executor runner.

Basically the tests generate a lot of files. To keep a clean file system, at the start of every pipeline I run this job, which just wipes the entire project build directory of any files left over from the last pipeline:

```yaml
cleanup_job:
    stage: cleanup_phase
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - sudo rm -rf *
        - sudo rm -rf .git
        - cd ~
        - sudo chown -R gitlab-runner builds/
```

Then the second job is meant to import the project with `GIT STRATEGY: fetch` and install it with Composer:

```yaml
install_framework:
    stage: setup
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
    script:
         - ls -la
         - eval $(ssh-agent)
         - ssh-add
         - composer install
         - cd ~
         - sudo chown -R gitlab-runner builds/
```

My problem is that, unless I delete the **/home/gitlab-runner/builds** folder before running my pipeline, the `install_framework` job fails during the initial fetch:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.7.1 (003fe500)
   on Local Runner vYk7fjSG
Using Shell executor...
Running on localhost.localdomain...
Fetching changes...
 /home/gitlab-runner/builds/vYk7fjSG/0/ent/qa/test_project/.git: Permission denied
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

This is extremely frustrating and I don't get why it happens. `.git` doesn't even exist at the point the fetch is being made seeing as I deleted it just prior.

Comment: Using sudo inside of your runner script, there seem to be something wrong with flow of your pipeline. I would redesign it. I don't know what you actually do so it is hard to help but if you need clean environment for every build so you can install something there, then docker runner seems like a better idea.

Comment: Using sudo is somewhat of a necessity unfortunately. `composer install` installs files that only `root` has access over, so it's necessary to remove them as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `clone` as my GIT_STRATEGY